# Use product images as utility images in Magento

Tags: image, magento, media, dashboard

I have to upload images through Magento admin/dashboard.
And use those images in a menu. I want to know the directory in which product images are uploaded and the path to that directory. 
Or if there is any standard way to upload images and media to Magento for general use like logos and GUI elements etc.
note: I do not have ftp logins of the site.

Comment: better ask at https://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to upload images to media storage root by going to insert image option in create new page you can reach there from Editor while editing pages or static blocks etc.

[image]

Following the above steps media storage is opened where we can upload media in root or new or old sub folders.

And then I used absolute paths to access the images like this https://<<.examplesite.com>>/media/wysiwyg/bird.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Magento product images are uploaded in media folder at the magento root. In that folder there will be product folder and subfolder according to the image name. You can get that path using:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl('media')
```

Also, you can use config fields in the admin section by using this link [link](https://www.kathirvel.com/adding-file-uploads-to-magento-admin-system-configuration/)

Thanks